# R cannot be resolved to a variable in Eclipse, and R.java missing

Tags: android, r.java-file

I know there are already a dozen posts with this name, but I have tried just about everything short of reinstalling eclipse, and I'm afraid if I do that I could just mess my project up even more. About half of the projects in my eclipse suddenly started getting this error, and half are fine (?!)

I've tried doing the project clean, restarting eclipse, rebooting computer, make sure no `import android.R`, deselecting Android in Java build path export etc.

Basically I started getting this error randomly after only changing a couple lines of code in my *.java* file, not any *.xml* files. Obviously I tried undoing those changes to no avail. I keep copies of my entire project backed up every few days or so, and always when it is a copy that compiles and runs ok. All the copies before a certain date are ok, and everything after get this error. All the bad copies have references to scoreloop and admob libraries, but I tried removing these libraries, no good. Also all the "ok before" copies were Android 2.1, and the bad ones are Android 2.3, but when I go into project build target and tell it to use 2.1 instead of 2.3, still no go.

Any ideas anyone?

edit: looked in error log and around when i started getting this problem started getting these:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-16 22:02:42.354
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-16 22:02:42.404
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-16 22:02:42.788
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-16 22:02:45.079
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US
!SESSION 2011-10-17 09:11:22.690 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2011-10-17 09:11:25.717
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-17 09:54:11.817
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-17 09:54:11.859
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-17 09:54:12.266
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2011-10-17 09:54:14.582
!MESSAGE Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2011-10-17 16:46:42.471
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching stb".
!STACK 0

Comment: This could be also an issue in the ADT itself. Did you upgrade it recently? (for example to r14 version)

Comment: i don't think so, i was on vacation so it was like day 5 of no internet when it happened.

Comment: Then try updating ADT (there's a new version with ICS)

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the /project/res folder.
If you're using linux, can you please post the output of ls -r XX/res?

Otherwise, are there any files other than folders in that folder?

Comment: did you try to compile from the command line?

Comment: I had this kind of problem under MacOS because Eclipse on Windows computer of my colleague messed up the `default.properties` file - replacing slash `/`, with few backslashes `\\ `  (or even `\\\\ `).

Comment: i am running on windows.  there is nothing unusual in the /res folder that i see.

Comment: Have you checked the "Console" and the "Error Log" windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem was with my android manifest file, i forgot that is an xml also. the section where there was some stuff added for scoreloop, one of the lines had a android:theme="@style/sl_dialog" which it suddenly didn't like anymore.  i still cant get any of the scoreloop imports to resolve, but there are only a few lines of code for that and when i comment them out at least my r.java builds now.

edit: it turns out the library for my scoreloop was messed up for some reason, i had to completely remove all references of scoreloop from the workspace and then reimport it back into the library and it ended up working again.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, if `R.java` is not being generated, there is a problem with one of your resource files or the manifest. Error messages should appear in the Eclipse console (note: *not* LogCat).

You might also consider trying [a command-line build via Ant](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) to see if that gives you more indications of what is afoot with your project.

Comment: this is the answer for my case. i put a image resource which is xx.jpg, but xx.png is located in the same folder. after i clean the project, R cannot generate. i remove the same file name and R generate again.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your SDK location in Eclipse.

Second, check for compiling errors (Sometimes eclipse didn't show them). You need to look it.

Third, Make cleanup project

Hope, it help you!

Comment: what do you mean by "check my location"? what should i be looking for? it hasn't moved. i performed project clean to no help, and i posted errors above, though not sure if they mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is either a problem with eclipse+adt or with the resources.

I guess it's the second case (otherwise switching back to an older version wouldn't fix the problem). So my guess is one of the resources is broken. For example a .9.png has a semitransparent pixel in the edge. Check the error log: "Window->Show view->Error log". Clear the error log and clean+rebuild the projects. If there are broken resources, it should be listed there. Also check for errors in the "Problems" view.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue after performing a clean - the clean had removed a color from an xml layout from

```
android:textColor="#FFF"
```

to 
    android:textColor=""

As Soon as the empty color was populated presto... it all worked.